# Xcode swift 2 HTML img src

Tags: html, ios, string, swift2, xcode7.1

I have a project written in Swift 2.0 that exports some `HTML` written text as a PDF.  I want to insert an image into my HTML but have to use quotations for the `<img src= "dividerImage.png">`.  It it is not accepting the quotes because it is already within the url `string` text quotations as shown:

```
url = "<h>Title of PDF</h> [image source text here] <body>PDF body text here</body>"
```

Is what I'm trying to do not possible?  I've search online for documentation on this in Swift 2.0 with no luck.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simple quote:

```
url = "<h>Title of PDF</h> <img src= 'dividerImage.png'> <body>PDF body text here</body>"
```

or escape double quote:

```
url = "<h>Title of PDF</h> <img src= \"dividerImage.png\"> <body>PDF body text here</body>"
```

Comment: Thank you.  I did not know about the single quote ( ' ).